# TensorFlow save & load inconsistency

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, save, load

I trained and saved a feed forward neural network for pixel classification problem using TensorFlow with the test accuracy of 95%. In this model, I have 11 features for each pixel. The problem arises when I save and then load the model. With the same input X and Y that I used in the original model, I get almost 0% accuracy for the loaded model. But I expect to get the same 95% accuracy! here is the sample code that I used:

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(1, 11))) # my input shape (13851000, 11) 
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(7))
model.summary()
optim = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.01, beta_1=0.9,
                                     beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-07,
                                     amsgrad=False, name='Adam') 

call1 = tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=3, verbose=0, mode='auto',
    baseline=None, restore_best_weights=False)

model.compile(optimizer=optim,
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(X_train, Y_train, epochs=100, validation_split = 0.2,
                    callbacks=[call1])
```

Here is the accuracy of the original model:

```
print('\nTest accuracy:', test_acc)

> Test accuracy: 0.9543394446372986
```

Now, When I save and load the model:

```
model.save('saved_model/my_model')
new_model = tf.keras.models.load_model('saved_model/my_model')
loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(X_test,  Y_test, verbose=2)
print('Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%'.format(100*acc))

> 432844/432844 - 439s - loss: 0.1413 - accuracy: 7.2197e-08
```

As you can see, the accuracy dropped significantly. Some additional info:

**info 1:** `Model.summary()` returns the same architecture in both cases.

**info 2:** `X_test.shape` returns a matrix with shape (13851000, 11), meaning 13851000 pixels each with 11 features

**info 3:** I get the following warning when I load and then evaluate the model:

WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (None, 1, 11) for input Tensor("flatten_input_4:0", shape=(None, 1, 11), dtype=float32), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (None, 11).

To solve this Warning I reshaped the X_Test, Y_Test to be 3 dimensional ((13851000, 1, 11), (13851000, 1)) and the warning was gone. However, I still got 0% accuracy.

**info 4:** `print(tf.__version__)` returns `2.3.0`.

**info 5:** `ls saved_model` return `my_model` and `ls saved_model\my_model` returns `assets variables saved_model.pb`

Note: I am working on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

If you did any pre-processingof the training data make sure you are doing the exact same pre-processing on your test data. For example if you rescaled the value of your pixels in the training samples do the same for the test samples.

Comment: I did. The exact same input on original model gives 95% accuracy, but the loaded model produce 0% accuracy!

Comment: I assume that before you saved the model you evaluated it against the test set and got 95% accuracy without any warnings. Then you saved the model, reloaded it and then tried to evaluated it using the EXACT same test set and got the warning. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. After loading the model I got that warning. Then, I tried to reshape the inputs to get ride of the warning but I still got the same results (without warning)